# ASP.NET Remove all items from ShopCart

Tags: asp.net

Hey I have ShoppCart class which contains items of Class cartItems

So I can run a functions like

```
ShoppingCart.Instance.AddItem(5, 5, 16.0, "First Product", 15, 10)

ShoppingCart.Instance.Items.Count

ShoppingCart.Instance.RemoveItem(productId)
```

Where the remove functions looks like

```
' RemoveItem() - Removes an item from the shopping cart
Public Sub RemoveItem(ByVal productId As Integer)
    Dim removedItem = New CartItem(productId)

    For Each item As CartItem In Items
        If item.Equals(removedItem) Then
            Items.Remove(item)
            Return
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

That removes one item, I am looking at a function which I can use to EMPTY my shopping cart i.e. on logout I tried Session.Abandon, but then I login again it still remember the items in my cart.

Comment: Silly -- but have you looked to see if your ShoppingCart has a `Clear` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling `ShoppingCart.Instance.Items.Clear();`

and just a random guess, if you are using sample cart code given here: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=423 (because it seems similar) then what you can also do is, in ShoppingCart class add a new method that clear all items like this:

```
public void RemoveAll() {  
Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what sort of list is being used in you shopping cart but you could try -

```
Items.RemoveAll()
```

**EDIT**

I think the 'RemoveAll()' method requires a predicate as an argument, which would mean you'd need to do something like this (which would work but is a weird thing to do) -

```
Items.RemoveAll(x => 1==1)
```

Or in vb

```
list.RemoveAll(Function(x) 1 = 1)
```

You could try this -

```
Items.RemoveRange(0, Items.Count)
```

Comment: No Clear Method available, and ShoppingCart.Instance.Items.RemoveAll() is looking for arugument.      Error is Error 399 Argument not specified for parameter 'match' of 'Public Function RemoveAll(match As System.Predicate(Of T)) As Integer'.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this

```
ShoppingCart.Instance.Items.RemoveAll()
```

EDIT

Not sure which collection is being used. I guess another simple way would be to reinitialize the collection

```
ShoppingCart.Instance.Items = new Items();
```

Comment: Thats gives the error Error 399 Argument not specified for parameter 'match' of 'Public Function RemoveAll(match As System.Predicate(Of T)) As Integer